# Need help link a "random" function in javascript to a mapped image

Tags: javascript, html, image, function, dictionary

So I have been having trouble linking my function to my website. Keep in mind this is all client side. Here is my JavaScript function:

```
function RandomButton() {
    var number=Math.floor((Math.random() * 3) + 1);
    if(number===1) {
        window.location.replace("../Mazerunner.html");
    }
    else if(number===2) {
        window.location.replace("../GoneGirl.html");
    }
    else if(number===3) {
       window.location.replace("../Dracula.html");
    }
```

Basically what is happening is that it picks a random number between 1 and 3 and if its 1 it goes to a webpage, ifs its 2 another page and so on. Now i do not know how to link this to my mapped image. This function might also not even be doing what i think its doing im quite new at javascript. Here is my image map code.

```
<map name="RandomMap">
    <area shape="rect" coords="0,0,500,500" onclick="RandomButton()" href="" alt="Random">
</map>
```

Im not sure what to do with href="" as I get an error if I just remove it.

Comment: You don't have a `}` to close your function. You may of forgot to add it when you copied your code and pasted it in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

do this :

```
href="javascript:RandomButton()"
```